# How to update Ruby version in Window?

Tags: ruby, window

I am trying to install an Amazon Web service gem into my project (I use window and Aptana RadRails) but it asked me to update current Ruby version (1.8.5) to 1.8.7.

I use InstantRails for Window platform. So could you tell me how can I upgrade my Ruby to new version?

Do I need to install new InstantRails? or Can I update with Ruby Gem? or may be there is your alternative idea for this activity. :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby-lang.org Downloads](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) The 1.8.7 binary is right there.

Answer (score 1):

Even better than the builds on ruby-lang.org is the preview versions of the Ruby Installer built with mingw which allows compiling of gems without Visual C++ 6.0.

- http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
- [Tutorials](http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/tutorials)